# Pass variables from UI to a chef server.

Tags: chef-infra

I have very little knowledge about chef. Is there any way to pass variables taken from a web user interface to a chef server? I have a interface from where i will be taking a name and i want to pass that to the chef server. Can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there are API bindings for just about every language. Chef-api for Ruby, PyChef for Python, jclouds-chef for Java. Take your pick and make a little webapp.

Comment: Can you help me with some code for the same using java.

Comment: Nope, been years since I touched Java, but the Jclouds project has some examples to get your started on the Chef side of things.

Comment: @KrishGambhir Please give it a try w/ the examples and then post specific questions if you run into problems. :)